# putting cat in the background freezes my shell

Tags: linux, shell

**INTRODUCTION**
UX
As a part of my course work I am writing my own shell in linux. I have problem in placing some of the processes in background.
I know that placing a '&' at the end of the command keeps the process in the background and the parent process(myShell) doesn't have to wait for it. It's work fine with ls -l &, firefox & etc.,

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem with which I am really concerned is cat &. Here when I run this command cat process goes to the background and I get back myShell(parent proc) prompt though I could type but myshell is getting frozen in a few seconds.

Do this have anything to do with blocking input etc.,
Any suggestions please? Thanks.

EDIT: Here's a function from my code that executes a command given from my shell as asked by @minitech

```
void executeCmd(char **cmdArgs, int inRedirectFd, int outRedirectFd, char *inFileName, char *outFileName, int bgProc, int inPipe, int outPipe, int *pipeFd1, int *pipeFd2){
int childPid;
childPid = fork();

if(childPid==0){

    //writing the pipes before the redirection because the redirection can overwrite pipes
    if(!inPipe && outPipe){
        close(pipeFd1[0]);
        dup2(pipeFd1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    }
    else if(inPipe && !outPipe){
        close(pipeFd1[1]);
        dup2(pipeFd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        }
    else if(inPipe && outPipe){
        close(pipeFd1[1]);
        close(pipeFd2[0]);
        dup2(pipeFd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipeFd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    }

    if(outRedirectFd==1){
        //token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        int fd = open(outFileName, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IROTH | S_IRGRP);
        if(fd==-1){
            printf("myShell: %s: %s\n", cmdArgs[0], strerror(errno));
        }
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
    }
    if(inRedirectFd==0){
        //token = strtok(NULL," ");
        int fd = open(inFileName, O_RDONLY | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IROTH | S_IRGRP);
        if(fd == -1){
            printf("myShell: %s: %s\n", cmdArgs[0], strerror(errno));
        }
        dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
    }

    execvp(cmdArgs[0], cmdArgs);
    printf("myShell: %s: %s\n", cmdArgs[0], strerror(errno));
    _Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else{
    if(!bgProc){
        int retStatus;
        waitpid(childPid, &retStatus, 0);
        //waitpid(childPid, &retStatus, 0);
        //printf("%d\n", retStatus);
    }
    else{
        //printf("parentDesn't Wait");
    }   
}
```

}

Throw any other suggestions that you could think of. Thank You.

Comment: Could you show your code, please?

Answer (score 5):

When `cat` is invoked without a file argument, it processes `stdin`. When you use `cat &`, it goes into background and waits for input from `stdin`. Since you are not providing a way to signal end of `stdin`, it waits for ever.

If you provide a file to `cat`, as in `cat test.txt &`, it will not freeze your shell.